# suggestions about integrating pointer into program

Tags: c, function, pointers

In a beginner program I am working on, I must use 3 functions to get the sum and difference of two arguments. On the third function, I have to store the result in two pointers. My issue is, I have not been able to successfully integrate the third function into main.

My main function is as follows:

```
int main ()
{
    int num1, num2;
    int sumResult, differenceResult;

    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Please enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    sumResult = CalculateSum (num1, num2);

    printf("the result of the sum is %d\n", sumResult);

    differenceResult = CalculateDifference (num1, num2);

    printf("the result of the difference is %d\n", differenceResult);

    return 0;
}
```

My function that deals with pointers :

```
void CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2, int*sumPtr, int *diffPtr)
{
    *sumPtr = num1+num2;

    *diffPtr= num1-num2;

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "integrate ... into main"  If you want the sum/difference calculated _directly in_ main, the solution seems obvious.  If you want to call your function _from_ mail, show us how you think it should work and we'll try to help correct you, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are used (usually) to pass not argument value but address in memory where argument value is located. This allows you to modify parameters value.

Let's take function that adds 2 to **argument** and passes result through **result** variable as an example:

```
void WrongAdd2(int argument, int result)
{
    result = argument + 2;
}
```

In this case you pass **result** value but any change in **result** will be local. 
Pointer instead tells not about value but address where value is located.

```
void Add2(int argument, int *result)
{
    *result = argument + 2;
}
```

Here **result** 'address of int' so ***result** is place in memory pointed by **result**.

To use pointers in functions you should have place in memory for result:

```
int value = 10;
int result = 0;

WrongAdd2(value, result); /* result is still 0. */
Add2(value, &result);     /* result is updated and now it is 12. */
```

So you need to call CalculateBoth with the same first 2 arguments but results will be passed through 3rd and 4th arguments which are pointers to places (contain their addresses) where you want to place output parameters.

```
CalculateBoth(num1, num2, &sumResult, &differenceResult);
```

You are telling: well, take values of **num1** and **num2** and pass ADDRESS OF **sumResult** and **differenceResult** as output parameters.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>To understand clearly read answer linearly</sub>

First understand you function declaration(read comments):

```
  void CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2,        int*sumPtr, int *diffPtr);  
// ^
// return type           ^--------^                 ^-----------^
//                  first two are simple int    last two are pointer to integers
```

Notice return type of your function is `void` means it doesn't return (or say return void).

But your function `CalculateBoth()` is good It calculate both *sum* and *difference*.(two things)

In C programming we can't return more then one argument from a function. And in this case pointer are very useful. So last you arguments are actually output arguments of function CalculateBoth() sun  and difference.

like(*again read comments*):

```
  void CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2,        int*sumPtr, int *diffPtr);  
// ^
// return type           ^--------^                 ^-----------^
//                  two input arguments        Output sum and difference
```

Because pass by value doesn't reflect change at calling statement we do use pass by address variable.

Pointers are variable that can hold address of other variable.

Because in `main()` function you need both sum and difference of both variables `num1` and `num2`. we pass address of two result variables when we call function `CalculateBoth()` from `main()`.

So you result variables in main() are:

```
int sumResult, differenceResult;
```

you from main like:

```
CalculateBoth(num1, num2, &sumResult, &differenceResult);
```

**Note**: ampersand operator `&` in front of variable `sumResult`, `differenceResult` is The [address-of operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caaw7h5s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) gives the address of its operand. By simple writing variable name you are passing value, but if you use `&` operator you passes address of a variable.

function `CalculateBoth()` having local copy of their variables. But in case of last two arguments function stores result at address instead of their local copy so result reflects in calling function `main()`.

```
void CalculateBoth(  int num1, int num2, int*sumPtr, int *diffPtr)
//variable types are:   value      value   address     address       
{
    *sumPtr = num1+num2;    //store result of + memory pointer
    *diffPtr= num1-num2;    //    by variable sumPtr, *diffPtr
}
```

**Note**: `*` here is [*value at address*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw63e3c3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operator gives value stored at an address. and The result of the operation is the value addressed by the operand; that is, the value at the address to which its operand points. So you are storing at memory pointer by two variables

So instead call your function:

```
differenceResult = CalculateBoth (num1, num2);
```

call like

```
CalculateBoth(num1, num2, &sumResult, &differenceResult);
```

additionally, you are doing wrong, if you writea `differenceResult =` in front of above function calling expression because `CalculateBoth()` returns nothing.

Comment: *let me know if you need more help regarding this, read other's answers also all have explained very good*

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how to do this, which assumes your `CalculateSum()` and `CalculateDifference()` functions appear before this code. (you didn't provide them in the source listing):

```
void CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2, int *sumPtr, int *diffPtr)
{
    *sumPtr = CalculateSum(num1, num2);
    *diffPtr= CalculateDifference(num1, num2);
}

int main ()
{
    int num1, num2;
    int sumResult, differenceResult;

    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Please enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    // invoke both sum an difference through a unified front-end
    CalculateBoth(num1, num2, &sumResult, &differenceResult);

    printf("the result of the sum is %d\n", sumResult);
    printf("the result of the difference is %d\n", differenceResult);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it like -

```
CalculateBoth(num1, num2, &sumResult, &differenceResult);
```

Not sure what you are misunderstanding here. For example -

```
*sumPtr = num1+num2;
```

Since `sumPtr` is pointing to `sumResult`, the result is acutally written to it. And you can print the calculated values in main once the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by integrate. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
CalculateBoth(num1, num2, &sumResult, &differenceResult)
```